# How to use partition function in C++ for container containing custom objects

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am trying to use the parititon() API to partition object stored in vector. I want to call a function object to parition the vector in two half. Following code give me compile error. How to do this in C++?

partition.cpp:15:48: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   auto itr = partition(v.begin(),v.end()-1,comp);

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class comp{
public:
  bool operator()(const pair<int,int>& p1, const pair<int,int>& p2) {
    return p1.first < p2.first;
  }
};


main(){
  vector<pair<int,int> > v = { {1,2} , {3,4} , {5,6} ,{7,8} };
  auto itr = partition(v.begin(),v.end()-1,comp);

}
```

Comment: Firstly, `comp` -> `comp{}`. Next, why your functor has two parameters? There has to be one.

Comment: If we dont have two argument how will i perform comparision ( i need atleast two pairs to compare whis is smaller).  Also i am not aware of  comp{} syntax. Please eloburate

Comment: I see partition only take uniary comparision function. So what is the my options in this case? how to i pass the second argument. Am i forced to use the lambda function and this can't be done using functor?

Comment: It is not order relative to each other, it is partition, based on some property of the element. UnaryPredicate means one parameter. So you could, f.e. partition elements below/above median, but not relative to each other

Comment: @David, this is partition, not sorting routine. If you want to sort, use sort

Comment: @David You haven't (or not fully detailed) the partitioning criteria.  What elements go to the "left" of the partition, and what elements go to the "right"?

Comment: @Severin but to know if the element is above or below median i need to pass median somehow to my functor.  How will i do that?

Comment: I don't understand.  You don't need to pass anything if you use a capture lambda.

Comment: That is what constructors and member variables are for.  That or just use a lambda and capture the computed median.

Comment: No i am looking for parition routine which partition pairs. all the pairs which are smaller than the "7" goes to left and the remaining goes to right!

Comment: @David Then do you know what a lambda is?  Or are you using a compiler that is not C++ 11 compliant?

Comment: I know what lambda is but i am not very much comfortable with them. I was wondering i can do this using functors?

Comment: If you want something resembling median, then do something like `median = (*max_element(b,e) + *min_element(b,e))/2; auto Predicate = [median](const X& e) {return e < median;}`

Comment: Then you provide a function object, i.e. an object with `operator()` overloaded.

Comment: that is (operator())  what i tried to do in my implemenation the question is how to make it work with just argument?

Comment: *but to know if the element is above or below median i need to pass median somehow to my functor. How will i do that?* Why are you partitioning around the median?  The median is the middle of a sorted list so they will already be in the right order.

Comment: Add a constructor to `comp` that takes your "7" argument.  Note that `comp` is a full-blown class -- it can have state.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got it ! , Why is the argument expectation of partition() different from sort(). Sort take two argument functor, Why don't we have a extention of of parittion which takes similar comparator function?

Comment: @David, just take a look at the answer. Partition works wrt some external requirement (carried by predicate). Sorting is based on internal order. THose two functions have different semantics - what if I really want to know how many samples below predicate I've got?

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help

Comment: @David Just FYI, there is also `std::stable_partition` method, which works like `partition` but preserves relative ordering, don't know if it might suit you better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
struct comp {
    int _median;
    comp(int median): _median(median) {
    }
    bool operator()(const pair<int,int>& p) {
        return p.first < _median;
    }
};
```

and then

```
auto i = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), comp{7});
```

Might want to add default copy ctr, move ctr, op=, dtr and other scaffolding

Answer (score 3):

[`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) might interest you to rearrange your range:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v = { {1,2} , {3,4} , {5,6} ,{7,8} };

auto mid = v.begin() + std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()) / 2;
std::nth_element(v.begin(), , v.end());
```

Now,

each element of range `[v.begin(), mid)` is less or equal to mid.
each element of range `(mid, v.end())` is greater or equal to mid.

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) the predicate is unary and therefore, it requires one argument.

As for how to pass the argument :

- `comp` is a class and cannot be passed as argument
- `comp{}` is a default constructed instance of `comp` which exposes the call operator